# Get Tags Value click method in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, input, tags

So I have implemented a tags input in my Angular app project. It works well with autocomplete except that when I click on a certain tag, it just only gets the value of the first index. 
[sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxFk8.png)

What I want to happen is that when I click on a certain tag, it will display its value within the input field.

My HTML goes like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputted" placeholder="Type to search Screening Form" (keyup)="displayBadge()"/>
<span *ngFor="let title of titles">
    <span class="label label-info" id="selected" (click)="useValue()">{{title}}</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up Jquery with Angular, you need to use **`ngModel`** with two way data binding, so that you can simply get the selected elemeent.

Comment: do you have any resource for this that you can share? thank you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-material-chips-auto-complete-iwgfmj?file=app/app.component.ts